# forward network in CNN

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, caffe

I am new to deep learning. I found there are two prototxt files when I used caffe, one is "deploy" and another is "train_val".
I know that "train_val" is used to train the model. But for the "deploy" file some people said it is for test the image.
So, my question is does the "deploy" only have `forward()` network so the test image data only go through the forward network for once to get the score?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you already noted there are some [fundamental differences between `'train_val.prototxt'` and `'deploy.prototxt'`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33773152/1714410).
One key difference is that `'deploy.prototxt'` usually lack any loss layer.
When you have no loss function defined for a net, there is no meaning of backward propagation: what gradients would you propagate? gradients of what function?

Therefore, a `net` object in caffe has `backward()` method implemented for all phases. Nevertheless, this method is meaningless when you test the net with no loss function (only prediction).

Answer (score 2):

ideally that is how it should work,but the files are just network definition.You can use one single file to both train and test.You have to specify what phase you you want some blobs to be availables,meaning you can definite two inputData layer ,one that would be used during training,and another used for testing and specify the corresponding phase like this:

```
 name: "MyModel"
layer {
  name: "data"
  type: "Data"
  top: "data"
  top: "label"
  include {
    phase: TRAIN
  }
  transform_param {
    mirror: false
    crop_size: 227
    mean_file: "data/train_mean.binaryproto" # location of the training data mean
  }
  data_param {
    source: "data/train_lmdb" # location of the training samples
    batch_size: 128 # how many samples are grouped into one mini-batch
    backend: LMDB
  }
}
layer {
  name: "data"
  type: "Data"
  top: "data"
  top: "label"
  include {
    phase: TEST
  }
```

During training, the previous layer will be used where the the second will be ignored.
During test phase,the first layer will be ignored the second layer will be used as input for testing.

Another point is that during testing ,we need the accuracy of our prediction as we don't need to update our weights anymore 
l

```
layer {
  name: "accuracy"
  type: "Accuracy"
  bottom: "fc8"
  bottom: "label"
  top: "accuracy"
  include {
    phase: TEST
  }
}
layer {
  name: "loss"
  type: "SoftmaxWithLoss"
  bottom: "fc8"
  bottom: "label"
  top: "loss"
}
```

if the include directive is not given,the layer is included in all phases.

Although you can include the accuracy layer also during training to see how the output are goings(ie: for measuring accuracy improvement after how many iterations),we need it more on predictions .
in your solver,you can specify `test_iter` to specify after how many iteration test operation will be carried out(You validate your model each test_iter iterations)

train_val and deploy file separate those two phases into two different files.All specification in train_val are related to the training phase. and deploy for testing.I am not sure,where the train_val combination came from,but i suppose it was due to the fact that you can validate your model after test_iter and continue to train again from there.
As you dont need the loss during test,rather than the probability,you can  use softmax for probability out function in stead of of softmaxwithloss  in deploy or you can have both defined.
The  caffe test command performs forward operation but doesn't do the backward()(back propagation) operation.I hope it helps